# Jsoup selectors: 2nd div after h2

Tags: java, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

...

<h2> Blah Blah 1</h2>
<p>blah blah</p>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Col 1 Header</th><th>Col 2 Header</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 1.1 Value</td><td>Line 2.1 Header</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 2.1 Value</td><td>Line 2.2 Value</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>Col 1 Header T2</th><th>Col 2 Header T2</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 1.1 Value T2</td><td>Line 2.1 Header T2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Line 2.1 Value T2</td><td>Line 2.2 Value T2</td></tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<h2> Blah Blah 2</h2>

<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>XCol 1 Header</th><th>XCol 2 Header</th></tr>
                <tr><td>XLine 1.1 Value</td><td>XLine 2.1 Header</td></tr>
                <tr><td>XLine 2.1 Value</td><td>XLine 2.2 Value</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<p>blah blah</p>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><th>XCol 1 Header T2</th><th>XCol 2 Header T2</th></tr>
                <tr><td>XLine 1.1 Value T2</td><td>XLine 2.1 Header T2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>XLine 2.1 Value T2</td><td>XLine 2.2 Value T2</td></tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**I would like to extract the 2nd DIV following an *h2* tag that contains a given text.**

As you may notice in the first and second div the **p** tags are not in the same position.

To extract the DIV following the first h2, the below formula would work:

```
h2:contains(Blah 1) + p + div +div
```

But to extract the 2nd, replacing "Blah 1" with "Blah 2" would not work as the ""p"" tag is located elsewhere , so a static selector would be :

```
h2:contains(Blah 2) + div + p +div
```

And what I need is a single selector formula where changing the text would make it work, wherever the p blocks may be

I tried several ways :
like ... The selector **nth-of-type** would not work either, because I know the position of the DIV only wrt the **h2** that is not father of DIV but a preceding sibling ...

Help please

Comment: Just to be clear "contains a given text": are you looking to select the 2nd div following an h2 tag that itself contains "blah 2"? If so, what's the function of the p tag? It would be much easier to do it with a library supporting xpath (like xsoup); is that an option?

Comment: I need iterativery to extract the 2nd DIV following an H2 that contains a text that changes at each iteration.

You are totally right Jack; Xpath would be great but unfortunately I am using a tool based on jsoup :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas how to achieve this.
The first one is to remove every `<p>` and then you will only have to select `"h2:contains(" + text + ")+div+div"`. Be careful and use it only when you're sure your `<div>` doesn't contain any `<p>`. Otherwise it will lack some content.

```
    public void execute1(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        // first approach: remove every <p> to simplify document
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        for (Element paragraph : paragraphs) {
            paragraph.remove();
        }
        // then one selector will return what you want in both cases
        System.out.println(selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText(doc, "Blah 1"));
        System.out.println(selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText(doc, "Blah 2"));
    }

    private Element selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText(Document doc, String text) {
        return doc.select("h2:contains(" + text + ")+div+div").first();
    }
```

The second approach would be to iterate over siblings of `"h2:contains(" + text+ ")"` and "manually" find second `<div>` ignoring anything else. It's better because it doesn't destroy the original document and it will skip any number of `<p>` elements.

```
    public void execute2(String html) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        System.out.println(selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText2(doc, "Blah 1"));
        System.out.println(selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText2(doc, "Blah 2"));
    }

    private Element selectSecondDivAfterH2WithText2(Document doc, String text) {
        int counter = 2;
        // find h2 with given text
        Element h2 = doc.select("h2:contains(" + text + ")").first();
        // select every sibling after this h2 element
        Elements siblings = h2.nextElementSiblings();
        // loop over them
        for (Element sibling : siblings) {
            // skip everything that's not a div
            if (sibling.tagName().equals("div")) {
                // count how many divs left to skip
                counter--;
                if (counter == 0) {
                    // return when found nth div
                    return sibling;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I had also third idea to use `"h2:contains(" + text + ")~div:nth-of-type(2)"`. It works for the first case, but fails for the second one probably because there's a `<p>` between the divs.

Comment: Hy Kristian,
I wanted to avoid using java but at the end there is no way to do it without coding:)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is by using the comma (`,`) query operator which does an OR between the selectors. So you can combine the two variations of where the `P` tag falls.

```
h2:contains(Blah 2) + div ~ div, h2:contains(Blah 2) ~ div + div
```

Here's an example on the [try.jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/~0x6sYFSlfteMjnRKSElGaYipcR0) playground.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 
I ended up writing some Java code as I cannot enumerate all possibles situations as  the provided code was for testin only but the HTM page I need to scrap i much more complex than it